# Need help in showing the POPup dialog in the UI while data loads in background async task

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a progress dialog in onPreExecute method of an async task but it doesn't show immediately while the async task fetches data from the DB. Can you suggest something that will display a progress dialog immediately on button click.. In the current scenario the screen freezes while its fetching data. Once fetched then it moves on to the next screen, but it doesn't show my progress dialog in the meanwhile. 
Below is the async task

```
public class waitAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ResultSet rs=null;
   private ProgressDialog processingDialog;
    static Connection conn=null;
    Statement stmt;
   // waitThread wt= new waitThread();
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      //  ProgressDialog processingDialog;
        super.onPreExecute();
        processingDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.mCon);
        processingDialog.show();
        processingDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_wait);
        //processingDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

    }
    @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {


            String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
            String ip = "mfb.dfsdfsdf.ap-north-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
            String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
            String db = "MyDatabase";
            String un = "xxxwww";
            String password = "xxxxxx";
            Class.forName(classs);

            String ConnURL = null;
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                    + password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);

            stmt = conn.createStatement(
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(params[0]);
            int size = 0;


            //conn.close();
            MainActivity.getdata=rs;
            MainActivity.flag=1;
            //Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.w("Error connection", "" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
        }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        processingDialog.dismiss();
      //  wt.interrupted();


    }



}
```

The call of async task from Main_Activity

```
Getdata(String bookid)
{
  String SQL="Select eb.book_name,eb.AuthorID,ma.Name,eb.GenreID_M,eb.GenreID_D,gm.Genre_MN+'- '+gd.Genre_DN as Genre,isnull(eb.pubDate,'') pubDate,isnull(eb.book_Loc,'') book_Loc,\n" +
                    " eb.Price,eb.ico_Loc,eb.Descrip from Master_ebook eb inner join Master_Author ma on eb.AuthorID=ma.Author_ID\n" +
                    " inner join Master_Genre_M gm on eb.GenreID_M=gm.Genre_MID\n" +
                    "inner join Master_Genre_D gd on eb.GenreID_D= gd.Genre_DID where eb.bookID=" + bookid;


            new waitAsync().execute(SQL);

            int c=0;
            while(MainActivity.flag==0)
            {
                c++;
            }

            if(MainActivity.flag==1)
            {
                MainActivity.flag=0;
                //processingDialog.dismiss();
            }

            ResultSet rs=MainActivity.getdata;
}
```

Comment: because obviously you had blocked UI thread with `while(MainActivity.flag==0)
            {
                c++;
            }` .... this code makes AsyncTask useless

Comment: what else can i do? can you please suggest? i will have to wait till my async task fetches my data because I will need that data immediately in the main activity getdata method

Comment: I think changes i made in your asynctask will be enough

Comment: i tried that, it doesn't effect anything. @Maharith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop like this after async task. It will block your UI thread.

```
while(MainActivity.flag==0) // wrong - blocking main thread
            {
                c++;
            }
```

You need to create a method in activity, say `onDataAvailable` and in this method
you can do whatever you want to do, either go to next activity or whatever, then call this method from `onPostExecute`

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        processingDialog.dismiss();
      //  call load complete method here


    }
```

Here is your updated async task.

```
public class WaitAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityRef;

    public WaitAsyncTask(MainActivity activity){
        activityRef = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
    }

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // show dialog
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // do you work in background
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
        super.onPostExecute(data);
        // hide dialog
        if(activityRef.get() != null){
            // call load completed method in activity
            activityRef.get().loadCompleted(data);
        }
    }
} // WaitAsyncTask
```

And in your `MainActivity`, create a method in which you want to receive results. I have create this method

```
  public void loadCompleted(String data){
        // this will be called automatically after fetching data is completed
    }
```

in `MainActivity` which I am calling from my task. You don't need while loop to wait. This method will be called after your data is fetched.

Comment: It's finally working.. Thanks a lot my friend @mallaudin

Comment: Glad to know that. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Pass activity context to async task through a constructor in asynctask and use that context instead. like

```
     Context mainActivityCtxt;  
     waitAsync(Context ctx) {
         this.mainActivityCtxt = ctx;
     };  

     new waitAsync(mainActivityCtxt).execute(SQL);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I tried that before, it gives an exception error "android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content". later I realized that i have to write  processingDialog.show(); before setContentView.

Comment: Then try using setMessage("some message") instead of setcontentview and check atleast dialog is displaying. Also, pass context through constructor instead of using through static reference.

Comment: You can't set `setContentView(R.layout.activity_wait);` before showing progress dialog.